# Can somebody help me understand my washing machine installation report?

Tags: plumbing, flooring, washing-machine

I had a integrated washing machine fitted yesterday due to the covid 19 situation I kept a good safety distance from them and there was minimal communication. The plumbers left without any explanation on what issues they had. Today his company sent me an installation report with below two issues and pictures. I know nothing about plumbing etc. Just trying to understand if these are serious issues and whether it'd be worth looking into soon. Thanks in advance for your help!

- Customer has no tap on the isolation valve - customer advised to get
  a new one

[image: failure 1]

- Tiles don't go all the way back customer advised to have flooring
  altered as there is just wood at the back which is not that stable
  for the machine.
  [image: failure 2]

Comment: I see the hot water cut-off valve (red).  Is there a cut-off valve where the cold water connects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Customer has no tap on the isolation valve - customer advised to get a new one

Looks like the cold water shutoff valve to which the hose is connected is missing the plastic handle. In the photo I can see the metal shank of the valve protruding upwards from the valve body, but there's no handle (like the red one on the hot water shutoff) on it so you can't really close the valve without using a tool. The plastic handle likely broke off some time in the past. You should consider having the valve replaced so that you can quickly shut water off if there's a leak.

> Tiles don't go all the way back customer advised to have flooring
>   altered as there is just wood at the back which is not that stable
>   for the machine.

Looking at the photo it seems that the back of the machine is sitting on a flat piece of wood while most of the machine is a bit above the floor. This might be a problem depending on the specific model of the machine, where its adjustable feet are located and whether they're sufficiently supported. You'll have to take a look into the gap underneath the machine and see if you need to fill it with something.